# How to create variables in Google Forms to output to Zapier

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms, zapier

I have a Google Form that works with Zapier. In addition, on submit of the Google Form, I created a Google Apps script to create a folder in Google Drive. But now I would like to output the Google Drive locations to Zapier as variables to use in the next workflow process.

In my Google Apps script I currently have:

```
function new_video_response(){
  try{
    const form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
    const folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER_ID');
    const responses=form.getResponses()[0];
    const answers=responses.getItemResponses();
    const NAME=answers[0].getResponse();
    const found=folder.getFoldersByName(NAME);
    const subfolder=found.hasNext()?found.next():folder.createFolder(NAME);
    const datetime=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'PST','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    console.log(datetime);
    const subsubfolder=subfolder.createFolder(datetime+' PST');
    answers[10].getResponse().forEach(ID=>DriveApp.getFileById(ID).moveTo(subsubfolder));
  }
  catch(error){console.log(error);}
}
```

When a form response is submitted I receive the following standard variables (in Zapier):

[image]

Is there a way or method to also pass the newly created Google Drive folder location to Zapier as well? Something like:

```
return {'subfolder_url':subfolder.getUrl()};
```

Comment: About `When a form response is submitted I receive the following standard variables (in Zapier):`, can I ask you about the details of the method for sending the submitted data of Google Form to Zapier? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I just attached my form to Zapier, and it outputs the response items with some standard variables like responseId and CreateTime. I'd like to add something to my new_video_response function to create a custom variable such as subfolder_url to pass the newly create location of the folder in Google Drive.

Comment: I do not understand the process by which the variables are sent to Zapier. That's what I am trying to find out so that I can pass my own.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that when Google Form is submitted if the submitted value is sent to Zapier using a script, your expected value might be able to be added to the script. But, from your reply, I cannot understand your situation. So, I'm not sure whether this can be used. For example, how about directly sending your expected data to Zapier using a Google Apps Script by the OnSubmit trigger? But, I'm not sure whether this can be used in your situation, because I cannot know your actual situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: I think the following answer might also apply: [Create google form response through API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75990164/1330560). Read the discussion about the REST API:  According to the documentation `The REST API does not plan to support:
Submitting form responses or Including detailed form or response data in the body of pub/sub notifications`