# Google Forms API Create New Variable with Response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using Google Forms API and I would like it to post a new variable when a response is submitted. In this [reference](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms.responses), when a response is given, the following JSON is sent:

```
{
  "formId": string,
  "responseId": string,
  "createTime": string,
  "lastSubmittedTime": string,
  "respondentEmail": string,
  "answers": {
    string: {
      object (Answer)
    },
    ...
  },
  "totalScore": number
}
```

I would like to create a custom variable on submit of a response in Google Apps Script connected to my Google Form:

```
"custom_var": "hello world!"
```

Something like:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
 set e.custom_var="hello world!";
}
```

Is this possible?

I need to pass more variables within responses that are created in order to use them for another application.

Comment: In your situation, you want to automatically add a custom value to the submitted values after the Google Form was submitted and before the submitted values are posted to another server. Or, are the submitted values posted to another server in your function `onFormSubmit`? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create google form response through API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989067/create-google-form-response-through-api)